# Compiling ffmpeg to support SPEEX decoding

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, speex

I am trying to compile ffmpeg to support Speex decoding. I have enabled speex decoding using the following flag --enable-libspeex in my shell script. I have also compiled speex 1.2rc1 downloaded from [this](http://www.speex.org/downloads/) link. After compiling the header files are available on this path /usr/local/include/speex. Following the above procedure when ffmpeg is compiled to produce support for SPEEX decoding I get the error libspeex not found.
Can anyone help me with this?

Config.log :

```
    BEGIN /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
    1   #include <math.h>
    2   float foo(float f, float g) { return roundf(f); }
    3   int main(void){ return (int) foo; }
    END /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
    xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -
    DPIC -arch armv7s -mios-version-min=6.0 -mcpu= -std=c99 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -
    mthumb -c -o /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.8q3GcEO3.o
    /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
    clang: warning: joined argument expects additional value: '-mcpu='
    xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7s -mios-version-min=6.0 -Wl,-dynamic,-
    search_paths_first -o /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.vFN4Vpqk
    /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.8q3GcEO3.o -lm -lz
    check_mathfunc sinf 1
    check_ld cc
    check_cc
    BEGIN /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
     1  #include <math.h>
     2  float foo(float f, float g) { return sinf(f); }
     3  int main(void){ return (int) foo; }
     END /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
     xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -
     DPIC  -arch armv7s -mios-version-min=6.0 -mcpu= -std=c99 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC - 
     mthumb -c -o /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.8q3GcEO3.o
     /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
     clang: warning: joined argument expects additional value: '-mcpu='
     xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7s -mios-version-min=6.0 -Wl,-dynamic,-
    search_paths_first -o /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.vFN4Vpqk
    /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.8q3GcEO3.o -lm -lz
    check_mathfunc trunc 1
    check_ld cc
     check_cc
    BEGIN /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
     1  #include <math.h>
     2  float foo(float f, float g) { return trunc(f); }
     3  int main(void){ return (int) foo; }
    END /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
     xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -
      DPIC -arch armv7s -mios-version-min=6.0 -mcpu= -std=c99 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -
     mthumb -c -o /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.8q3GcEO3.o 
    /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
    clang: warning: joined argument expects additional value: '-mcpu='
    xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7s -mios-version-min=6.0 -Wl,-dynamic,-               search_paths_first -o /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.vFN4Vpqk /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.8q3GcEO3.o -lm -lz
check_mathfunc truncf 1
check_ld cc
check_cc
BEGIN /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
    1   #include <math.h>
    2   float foo(float f, float g) { return truncf(f); }
    3   int main(void){ return (int) foo; }
END /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DPIC -arch armv7s -mios-version-min=6.0 -mcpu= -std=c99 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -mthumb -c -o /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.8q3GcEO3.o /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
clang: warning: joined argument expects additional value: '-mcpu='
xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7s -mios-version-min=6.0 -Wl,-dynamic,-search_paths_first -o /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.vFN4Vpqk /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.8q3GcEO3.o -lm -lz
check_lib speex/speex.h speex_decoder_init -lspeex
check_header speex/speex.h
check_cpp
BEGIN /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
    1   #include <speex/speex.h>
    2   int x;
END /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DPIC -arch armv7s -mios-version-min=6.0 -mcpu= -std=c99 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -mthumb -E -o /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.8q3GcEO3.o /var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c
clang: warning: joined argument expects additional value: '-mcpu='
/var/folders/5p/cffcbsm954b632yfzq4jrbbw0000gn/T//ffconf.5U5MfgMb.c:1:10: fatal error: 'speex/speex.h' file not found
#include <speex/speex.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
ERROR: libspeex not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your gcc is not looking in `/usr/local/include` or your dynamic linker does not have `/usr/local/lib` in its path.

Recompile speex and pass the `--prefix=/usr` option to configure.

Comment: I have tried to configure speex with --prefix=/usr. Then I tried make install, I got an error of /usr/lcoal/include/lib/pkgconfig/speexdsp.pc Permissions denied. So tried the command sudo make install and then I didn't get any error in installing speex. After these steps again I have configured ffmpeg for speex but still the same error. I am posting the some lines from config.log in the edits of my question

Comment: Where is speex.h installed? If it is in /usr/include/speex.h, then create a directory ``speex`` and move it there - making it in the ``/usr/include/speex/speex.h``